# AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.0-7396180-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon

Tags: gradle, bitrise

I am getting error on CI pipeline "",
when I upgraded to Android SDK 34.

I am using gradle version 7.0.2
gradle wrapper : distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip
AGP : com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction

> AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.0-7396180-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

Please help to resolve issue. I am blocked since many days.

I tried upgrading to AGP to 7.4.2 and gradle version to 7.5.

But many test cases are failing.